# How can I find out the default applications on Linux - CentOS/Ubuntu - using the command line?

Tags: linux

How can I find out the default applications on Linux - CentOS/Ubuntu - using the command line?

I tried to use `xdg-mime` and read the environment variables using `printenv`, but no result. I just need a command to tell me:

- This is the default browser
- This is the default mail client
- This is the default office suite
- This is the default antivirus
- This is the default firewall
- This is the default antispyware

Comment: Why? If you need to open a file with its default program, run xdg-open.

Answer (score 11):

You should find what you are looking for in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and/or `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.

For example, I have:

```
-> cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep mailto
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
-> cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep http  
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
```

Note that what is defined in the `mime` files of your home directory have priority over the ones in `/usr/share/applications`.

You can also use `xdg-mime`:

```
-> xdg-mime query default text/x-c               
emacs24.desktop
-> xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http 
exo-web-browser.desktop
```

If you also have `exo-something.desktop` (xfce), you can check what it is with `exo-preferred-applications`.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu but don't work on CentOS: No such file or directory.

Comment: @NeaguV For both of them? Maybe you have a `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`?

Comment: It is not ok becouse it returns: x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop --- and i dont know witch one is the default one !!

Comment: @NeaguV I believe it's the first one (if installed). You can check by running `xdg-open http://stackexchange.com/`. I edited my answer, you can use `xdg-mime` to get the default application without alternatives.